# Refreshing a ListView after an element was added

Tags: c#, data-binding, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am quite new to Windows development and of course even newer to Metro style app development. I am not sure I understand how Data Binding works.

I have a list of items.

```
private List<Expense> _expenses = new List<Expense>();
public List<Expense> Items
{
    get
    {
        return this._expenses;
    }
}
```

Which I bind to the XAML. (I use the Split Page template)

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = _data.Items;
    }
```

Then I display it

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView
    x:Name="itemListView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    Margin="120,0,0,60"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
    SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultListItemTemplate}"/>
```

Which works fine. Then when the user clicks on a Button I add a new item to my list

```
_data.Items.Add(new Expense
{
    Total = 100,
    When = new DateTime(2013, 6, 6),
    For = "Myself"
});
```

I was expecting that the `ListView` would refresh automagically since I set `Mode=TwoWay` but it does not. Did I misunderstand the concept and it is not possible for the list to refresh? Otherwise, what could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to have the UI update after you make changes to the collection you need it to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  This will notify the UI when a change occurs and it will respond by rebinding the UI on top of the change.

Implementing this interface is fairly involved though.  Instead you should just use `ObservableCollection<T>` in place of `List<T>` and the scenario should work just fine

```
private ObservableCollection<Expense> _expenses = new ObservableCollection<Expense>();
public ObservableCollection<Expense> Items
{
    get
    {
        return this._expenses;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. On the same subject, how to notify when an object itself changed?

Comment: @Jonas objects themselves must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`